# Vue error compiler with function never used

Tags: javascript, vue.js

could you please help me with resolve problem, why compiler say, that function 'show' is defined but never used?

function show is use in html:

```
<b-card>
  <div id="draw-image-test">
    <canvas
      id="canvasId"
      ref="canRef"
      @mousemove="show"
    />
  </div>
</b-card>
```

And after `<script>`

```
function show(){
  const canvasMouseTrack = document.getElementById('canvasId')
  const rect = canvasMouseTrack.getBoundingClientRect()
  console.log(rect.offsetX)
}
```

And i have error:

```
'show' is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function `show` should be added to the `methods` option :

```
<script>
  export default{

   methods:{
    show:function(){
      const canvasMouseTrack = document.getElementById('canvasId')
      const rect = canvasMouseTrack.getBoundingClientRect()
      console.log(rect.offsetX)
    }
    }
}
```